# 82 seconds to extract one row in the db, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded, with large database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, garbage-collection, glassfish

I added 100 000 rows to a the table in database (localhost) and since then I get [this error](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I resolved the problem by typing in consol:

```
javaw -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

And the consol the output is (see code below for context) :

```
2015-08-02T02:57:22.779+0200|Info: 5
2015-08-02T02:57:22.779+0200|Info: end, time taken: 82755
```

It takes 82 seconds to extract one row in the database(see code  at the end).
It was working fine when I had less rows so I'm wondering:

- Why would it take so much time to extract 1 row ? JPA can't possibly extract every row in an object ? Or does it ? Just wow.
- Is there a way around this ? I mean extracting a single row in 80 seconds is borderline slow.
- Do I really have to type the command `-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC`?
  What does it do ? From [the doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) :

> Use concurrent mark-sweep collection for the old generation.
>   (Introduced in 1.4.1)

Here is how my code is:

```
@EJB
private ThreadLookUpInterface ts;

@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/1", second = "0", persistent = false)
@Override
public void makeTopThreadList() {
    System.out.println("" + ts.getThread(5).getIdthread());
}
```

my service ejb like this:

```
@Stateless
public class ThreadLookUpService implements ThreadLookUpInterface {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    private static final String FIND_THREAD_BY_ID = "SELECT t FROM Thethread t WHERE t.idthread=:id";

    @Override
    public Thethread getThread(int threadId) {
        Query query = em.createQuery(FIND_THREAD_BY_ID);
        query.setParameter("id", threadId);
        try {
            Thethread thread = (Thethread) query.getSingleResult();
            return thread;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thethreads")
@NamedQuery(name = "Thethread.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Thethread t")
public class Thethread implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idthread;

    private String content;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_posted")
    private Date datePosted;

    private int downvotes;

    @Column(name = "hot_score")
    private int hotScore;

    @Column(name = "is_pol")
    private String isPol;

    private String title;

    private String type;

    private int upvotes;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Category
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thethread", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> categories;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thethread", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Post> posts;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Category
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_idcategory")
    private Category category;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Post
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_post")
    private Post post;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "posted_by")
    private User user;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ThreadVote
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thethread", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ThreadVote> threadVotes;

    public Thethread() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> command -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC? What does it do?

It sets the Garbage Collector: ConcurrentMarkSweep (CMS).
The Java Heap (where objects reside during their life cycle) is partioned mainly in two: Young and Old generation. Garbage collector is in charged of clean the heap applying some algorithms or strategies on this partitions. 
Instead of stopping the application threads during a full garbage collect like default GC does, CMS uses one or more background threads to periodically scan through the *Old generation* and discard unused objects.
This help you to reduce your overhead situations but the problem doesn't disappear.

> extract every row in an object ? Or does it ? Just wow.Is there a way around this ? I mean extracting a single row in 80 seconds is borderline slow.

The answers first at all depends on your entity model. For example and a common problem is abuse of Eager fetch type, which cause fetch/retrieve a lot of unnecessary object executing several query statements for that.
Also depends on how resolves the task your JPA implementation and the database but I suggest you start reviewing the entity model. Maybe if you post `Thethread` entity someone could recognize possible issues.

Comment: thanks. I posted my Thethread entity. It seems like some column have eager fetch type. I'm gonna look into this.